# Como fazer updates atomicos com TrieMap e ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concorrência, scala

Em Java [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) possui uma propriedade interessante. Operações como `putIfAbsent`, `remove`, `replace`, `computeIfAbsent`, `computeIfPresent`, `compute` e `merge` são atômicas.

Exemplo:

```java
final Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10000)
         .parallel()
         .forEach(i -> map.merge("key" + (i % 5 + 1), i, Integer::sum));
final long total = map.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum(); // 50005000
```

Eu não encontrei nenhuma operação similar na API do [`TrieMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/collection/concurrent/TrieMap.html):

```
val map = TrieMap[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
(1 to 10000).par.foreach(i => map(s"key${i % 5 + 1}") += i)
val total = map.values.sum // valor aleatório, += não é uma operação atomica
```

Claramente é possível sincronizar operações manualmente bem como usar construções como [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), [STM](https://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/), etc:

```
(1 to 10000).par.foreach(i => {
  val key = s"key${i % 5 + 1}".intern
  key.synchronized {
    map(key) += i
  }
})
```

Alternativamente, é possível utilizar `ConcurrentHashMap` do Java diretamente (sem usar [`asScala`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html)):

```
val map = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]()
(1 to 10000).par.foreach(i => map.merge(s"key${i % 5 + 1}", i, Integer.sum _))
val total = map.values().asScala.sum
```

Há alguma maneira mais simples / idiomática de garantir *updates* atomicos em um `concurrent.Map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Scala 2.12.x

Para quem ainda está na versão 2.12.x, segue uma solução com [Compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) que funciona corretamente:

```scala
val map = TrieMap[String, Int]()
(1 to 10000).par.foreach { i =>
  val key = s"key${i % 5 + 1}"
  map.putIfAbsent(key, 0)

  Iterator.continually(map(key)).find { oldValue =>
    map.replace(key, oldValue, oldValue + i)
  }
}
val total = map.values.sum
```

No exemplo acima o `TrieMap` pode ser substituído por um `concurrent.Map` sem prejuízos para a solução:

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val map = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]().asScala
```

### Scala 2.13.x

Dito isso, desde que fiz essa pergunta três anos se passaram e muita coisa mudou. A versão mais atual de Scala no momento que estou escrevendo essa resposta é a 2.13.4. De 2018 para cá:

- Coleções paralelas foram movidas para o seu próprio módulo: [`scala-parallel-collections`](https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections).

  Esse modulo agora precisa ser incluído como dependência do projeto:

  ```
  libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "1.0.0"
  ```

  E o uso do método `par` requer que você importe conversores implícitos:

  ```scala
  import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._

  val parallelRange = (1 to 10000).par
  ```
- Algumas operações que não eram atômicas passaram a ser. Por exemplo o método: `TrieMap.getOrElseUpdate` (ver [Issue 7943](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7943)).
- Alternativas para as operações do Java 8 foram introduzidas. E.g., a contrapartida do [java.util.Map#compute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) no Java é [scala.collection.mutable.Map#updateWith](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#updateWith(key:K)(remappingFunction:Option%5BV%5D=%3EOption%5BV%5D):Option%5BV%5D).

Em Scala 2.13.x o código acima pode ser reescrito de maneira mais idiomática:

```scala
val map = TrieMap[String, Int]()
(1 to 10000).par.foreach { i =>
  map.updateWith(s"key${i % 5 + 1}") {
    case Some(c) => Some(c + i)
    case None    => Some(i)
  }
}
val total = map.values.sum
```

No exemplo acima também podemos substituir o `TrieMap` por um `concurrent.Map`, porém os conversores foram migrados para outro pacote:

```scala
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val map = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]().asScala
```